# Python - Convert Octal to non-English Text from file

Tags: python, python-2.7, encoding, octal

I am trying to convert Non-English file encoded in **Octal** back into it's native format and store it in another file. The files include:

- i_file :  The input Original File with Octal Encoded text
- o_file :  The output Target File which should contain the Kannada(The non-English Language in question) text.
- octal_to_text.py : The python program that should take the octal text in in the input file and generate corrusponding non-English text in the target file.

Sample **i_file**

```
\340\262\270\340\263\215-\340\262\207+\340\262\241\340\263\215
\340\262\205-\340\262\246\340\263\215+\340\262\255\340\263\215
\340\262\205-\340\262\252\340\263\215+\340\262\252\340\263\215
\340\262\250\340\263\215-\340\262\205+\340\262\265\340\263\215
\340\262\205+\340\262\246\340\263\215
\340\262\266\340\263\215-\340\262\206+\340\262\270\340\263\215
\340\262\246\340\263\215-\340\262\205+\340\262\252\340\263\215
\340\262\244\340\263\215-\340\262\205+\340\262\237\340\263\215 \340\262\250\340\263\215-\340\262\205+\340\262\265\340\263\215
\340\262\247\340\263\215-\340\262\205
\340\262\247\340\263\215-\340\262\212
\340\262\205-\340\262\234\340\263\215+\340\262\206
\340\262\263\340\263\215-\340\262\205
\340\262\263\340\263\215-\340\262\207
\340\262\263\340\263\215-\340\262\211
\340\262\212+\340\262\263\340\263\215 \340\262\247\340\263\215-\340\262\212
sp
\340\262\256\340\263\215-\340\262\217+\340\262\262\340\263\215
\340\262\254\340\263\215-\340\262\216+\340\262\237\340\263\215
\340\262\260\340\263\215-\340\262\205+\340\262\271\340\263\215
\340\262\252\340\263\215+\340\262\260\340\263\215 \340\262\205-\340\262\252\340\263\215+\340\262\252\340\263\215
\340\262\265\340\263\215-\340\262\207+\340\262\270\340\263\215 \340\262\270\340\263\215-\340\262\207+\340\262\241\340\263\215
\340\262\217-\340\262\225\340\263\215+\340\262\205
\340\262\211+\340\262\227\340\263\215 \340\262\263\340\263\215-\340\262\211
\340\262\243\340\263\215-\340\262\205+\340\262\227\340\263\215
\340\262\212-\340\262\256\340\263\215+\340\262\254\340\263\215
\340\262\250\340\263\215-\340\262\216+\340\262\263\340\263\215
\340\262\216+\340\262\244\340\263\215
\340\262\205-\340\262\260\340\263\215+\340\262\256\340\263\215
\340\262\260\340\263\215+\340\262\205
\340\262\260\340\263\215+\340\262\206 \340\262\260\340\263\215+\340\262\205
\340\262\260\340\263\215+\340\262\207
\340\262\260\340\263\215+\340\262\212 \340\262\260\340\263\215+\340\262\207
\340\262\260\340\263\215+\340\262\223 \340\262\260\340\263\215+\340\262\207
\340\262\255\340\263\215-\340\262\205+\340\262\246\340\263\215
\340\262\205-\340\262\247\340\263\215+\340\262\257\340\263\215
\340\262\211-\340\262\237\340\263\215+\340\262\211
\340\262\206+\340\262\225\340\263\215
\340\262\205-\340\262\260\340\263\215 \340\262\205-\340\262\260\340\263\215+\340\262\256\340\263\215
\340\262\250\340\263\215-\340\262\250\340\263\215+\340\262\205
\340\262\250\340\263\215-\340\262\250\340\263\215+\340\262\206 \340\262\250\340\263\215-\340\262\250\340\263\215+\340\262\205
\340\262\250\340\263\215-\340\262\250\340\263\215+\340\262\207 \340\262\250\340\263\215-\340\262\250\340\263\215+\340\262\205
\340\262\250\340\263\215-\340\262\250\340\263\215+\340\262\211 \340\262\250\340\263\215-\340\262\250\340\263\215+\340\262\205
\340\262\250\340\263\215-\340\262\250\340\263\215+\340\262\212 \340\262\250\340\263\215-\340\262\250\340\263\215+\340\262\205
\340\262\250\340\263\215-\340\262\250\340\263\215+\340\262\222 \340\262\250\340\263\215-\340\262\250\340\263\215+\340\262\205
\340\262\220-\340\262\250\340\263\215
\340\262\206-\340\262\252\340\263\215+\340\262\206 \340\262\205-\340\262\252\340\263\215+\340\262\252\340\263\215
\340\262\206-\340\262\252\340\263\215+\340\262\223 \340\262\205-\340\262\252\340\263\215+\340\262\252\340\263\215
\340\262\222-\340\262\246\340\263\215+\340\262\205
\340\262\225\340\263\215-\340\262\222+\340\262\237\340\263\215
\340\262\205-\340\262\270\340\263\215+\340\262\205
\340\262\205-\340\262\270\340\263\215+\340\262\207
\340\262\205-\340\262\256\340\263\215+\340\262\270\340\263\215 \340\262\212-\340\262\256\340\263\215+\340\262\254\340\263\215
\340\262\244\340\263\215-\340\262\205+\340\262\260\340\263\215
\340\262\230\340\263\215-\340\262\205 \340\262\263\340\263\215-\340\262\205
\340\262\265\340\263\215-\340\262\206+\340\262\227\340\263\215 \340\262\266\340\263\215-\340\262\206+\340\262\270\340\263\215
\340\262\270\340\263\215-\340\262\205+\340\262\270\340\263\215 \340\262\244\340\263\215-\340\262\205+\340\262\260\340\263\215
\340\262\244\340\263\215-\340\262\211+\340\262\265\340\263\215
\340\262\257\340\263\215
```

The code i thought would work would be to convert the text into a byte array using `bytearray()`, then decode it to `utf-8` and write it to the targe file. **octal_to_text.py**

```
"""
Convert file contents from Octal to text

"""

with open('i_file','r') as tl, open('o_file','w+') as tk:
    for line in tl.readlines():
        line = (line.strip())
        br = bytearray(line)
        tk.write("{}\n".format(br.decode('utf-8')))
```

In the code above however, the output file generated is the same as the input. `bytearray` doesn't seem to be doing anything. What exactly am I doing wrong here? Could you provide a python2.7 solution?

**NOTE** The output file should contain characters like the ones shown below

```
ಅ
ಆ
ಇ
ಈ
ಉ
ಊ
ಋ
ಎ
ಏ
ಐ
ಒ
ಓ
ಔ
ಕ್
ಖ್
ಗ್
ಘ್
ಚ್
ಛ್
ಜ್
ಝ್
ಟ್
ಠ್
ಡ್
ಢ್
ಣ್
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `print` statement for an Octal encoded string, decodes Octal to the non-English notation only when working the python interpreter.

Thus, a simple work around is to perform the following steps:

1. Copy the contents of the file to be decoded
2. Open the python interpreter and assign the file contents to a
   variable in a multi line string.
3. Print the variable
4. Copy contents to a new file